# find a difference between current value and previous value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I need to find a difference between current value and previous value

Here is an example:

[image]

Here is required Output:

[image]

Explanation of output:  We need to have a difference between current value and previous value and need to find value_diff.

E.g. We have 500 in 1Q16 and 2Q16 so, Difference between both of them is 0..So, It needs to display 0 in value_diff column in 2Q16 rows.

We have 1000 in 3Q16 so, Differnce between 3Q16 and 2Q16 is 500.. So, it needs to display 500 in value_diff column in 3Q16  row.

I tried some coding using CTE but I did not find a perfect way to do this one..

Any advice would be helpful..

Comment: `3Q16` is very bad for ordering. I'd change it to `16Q3` if it's not too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2012+ supports `lag()` which does this directly.  In SQL Server 2008, I would recommend a `outer apply`.  Let me first assume that `quarter` is a reasonable format that orders correctly, such as YYYY-Q:

```
select t.*, (t.value - tprev.value) as diff
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.id = t.id and
            tprev.yyyyq < t.yyyyq
      order by tprev.yyyyq desc
     ) tprev;
```

You have a lousy format for `quarter`.  Let's fix that with a CTE:

```
with t as (
      select e.*,
             ('20' + right(quarter, 2)) + '-' + left(quarter, 1)) as yyyyq
      from example e
     ) 
select t.*, (t.value - tprev.value) as diff
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.id = t.id and
            tprev.yyyyq < t.yyyyq
      order by tprev.yyyyq desc
     ) tprev;
```